# parsing configuration into arguments in powershell

Tags: powershell, variables, ip, member

I'm working with PowerShell to develop a script that will push configuration changes via SSH to a managed device.  There are three variables in the configuration I need to capture: Group name, Member number (edit X), and Host IP.  They are all on different lines but are part of a logical section of code.  An example being:

```
edit "Cool Group Bro"
    set variable1
    set variable2
    set variable3
    set variable4
        config realservers
           edit 1
              set ip aa.bb.cc.dd
           next
           edit 2
              set ip ee.ff.gg.hh
           next
        end
end
```

There are multiple iterations of the Groups within the larger configuration.  I've been able to parse with RegEx to get a list of each variable "group" "member" "host", but lining up each in one logical configuration push is what I'm having trouble with.  Essentially what I'd like to do is end up with something that takes all three variables, and pushes some code like this:

```
edit "Cool Group Bro"
config realservers
edit 1
<set some additional variable>
end
end
```

Is there a cmdlet that I can use that would drill down to the lowest common denominator, ie. host, then work its way back through the member id up to the group name? Any suggestions or documentation that might be helpful?